# Is there a way to target some reac-bootstrap component css?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is there any way to target some components from `react-bootstrap` in `CSS`. For my application, I'm using Modals from `react-bootstrap` and I need to change some style on all of them and it will be annoying if I need to change every single one individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however you will need to inspect the Modal using ChromeDevTools or the like and see what classes are applied to the Modal when it is displayed. For example, when I inspected the Modal from react-bootstrap, I noticed the styles applied to the heading were given the className of "modal-header". So I created a Modal.css file and added the following code to it:

```
.modal-header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then, I imported "./Modal.css" into the Modal.js file or wherever you've defined or using your Modal. Finally, when I opened the Modal, the heading had a background of red color so to speak.

Please note that it can be a little difficult to override bootstrap styles sometimes.